# Web Api Json Post Request Does not bind the Model in the action

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler, model-binding

I'm building a web api application. I have a controller with a simple action that gets an object as parameter.

The Object looks like this :

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
 }
```

My Controller Action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Event e)
    {
    }
```

When I compose an http post request using Fiddler that looks like this:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:34860
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: application/json;


{
 "Id":"1",
 "ParentId":"0"
}
```

My object is null and I get http 502 error back on fiddler.

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: what is the name of the controller and what address are you using for the post ?

Comment: The Address is "http://localhost:34860/em/events" and the Controller Name is "EventsController". I'm able to hit the beak point on the action, but the parameter is null. I created a new simple web api solution and it works there ! I have no freaking idea what's the difference !

Comment: loose the "" in the values your model is for integers

Comment: Well, that doesn't really matter as the model binder is able to bind the values to the right types

Comment: try this {
    "id":1,
    "parentId":2
}

Comment: I did, it's still null ! .... :(

Comment: There must be something wrong with EntityFramework Core. When I removed all references to that, it worked .... !!!!!!

Comment: Well, not even that, If my Model is in another project Model Binder cannot bind it .... I have a DAL project that has my model, when I add the reference it's unable to bind it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116634/discussion-between-juan-and-pouyan).